# Is there a good way to solve recursion questions?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I am trying to solve this question

> Implement a function **substring** which takes in a **string** and returns all its possiblesubstrings.
>   A string  is a substring of a string  if either (1)  is an empty string, or (2) all characters in 
>   occur in  and in their relative left-and-right order. We assume that the original string 
>   does not contain any duplicate characters.

For instance,

```
>>>substring('a')
['', 'a']
>>> substring('abc')
['', 'c', 'b', 'bc', 'a', 'ac', 'ab', 'abc']
```

You must use the following code

```
def substring(S):
    if S ==[]:
    else:
```

I have only recently learn about recursion and tried to use this code.

```
def substring(S):
    if S ==[]:
        return ['']
    else:
        return[substring(S[1:])]+[substring(S[0])]
```

How do I solve this question and is there any advise I can get on how to solve these types of question?

Update: after reading the comments and answers, the answer that I can get is the following. However, the base case for this code is `S == ''` and not `S == []` which is required in the question.

```
def substring(S):
    if S =='':
        return ['']
    else:
        return substring(S[1:])+[S[0] + i for i in substring(S[1:])]
```

@Primusa Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm assuming you can't use a module that does this like itertools.combinations  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/itertools-combinations/problem . Is that right?

Comment: @zhenhir That is correct I only can use inbuilt functions

Comment: Recursion isn't actually the simplest way to solve this. Consider that each substring is the result of apply an `n`-bit mask to the original string of length `n`. Each bit determines whether you include the corresponding letter (bit is 1) or not (bit is 0) in the result. Then realize that all such masks can simply be interpreted as the binary representations of the numbers 0 to 2**n - 1. So given `abc`,  `''` is 0, `bc` is 3 (binary 011), `ab` is 6 (binary 110), etc.

Comment: @chepner Sorry I do not get what you are saying. However, I think the question is forcing me to use recursive by putting the base case there?

Comment: At each recursive step consider one character - it can either be in the sequence or not in the sequence. Something like `return [S[0] + i for i in substring(S[1:])] + substring(S[1:])` should do

Comment: Can characters be repeated in the substrings? ie: are the substrings of 'aa' ('a', 'aa', '') or just ('a', '')?

Comment: @Zhenhir 'We assume that the original string  does not contain any duplicate characters.'

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what your task is, but I would not suggest recursion here. This is a simple code (see also comment of @chepner)

```
S = 'abc'
l = list(S)

result = []
for n in range(2**len(l)):
    result.append(''.join([l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if 2**i & n > 0]))

print(result)
```

Comment: You totaly ignored the "You must use the following code" specified in the question

Comment: agree, formally we can integrate this solution with the required code, but this is useless, so this code most likely means recursion call